# Use Dedekind's Theorem to show that there does not exists $b$ such that $O_K=\mathbb{Z}[b]$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

This is a past exam question that I couldn't quite nail down. Any help is much appreciated!

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d_1}, \sqrt{d_2})$ where $d_1$ and $d_2$ are both $1$ mod $3$. Moreover $d_1$ and $d_2$ are square-free. The question asks why does it not exist a $b\in O_K$ such that $O_K=\mathbb{Z}[b]$, using Dedekind's theorem on factorising $(p)$ in $O_K$ where $p$ is a rational prime (i.e., just a prime number in the normal sense).

So I factored $(3)$ into the following $(3)=(3,b_1)(3,b_2)(3,b_3)(3,b_4)$ where $b_1=\sqrt{d_1}+\sqrt{d_2}+\sqrt{d_1d_2}, b_2=\sqrt{d_1}-\sqrt{d_2}-\sqrt{d_1d_2},b_3=-\sqrt{d_1}+\sqrt{d_2}-\sqrt{d_1d_2}, b_4=-\sqrt{d_1}-\sqrt{d_2}+\sqrt{d_1d_2}.$ Each factor is a prime ideal and I am convinced that up to this stage everything is correct.

Use Dedekind's Theorem I found that $[O_K:\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d_1}+\sqrt{d_2}]]$ is divisible by $3$ because otherwise the decomposition of $(3)$ will look really different from the one I wrote above.

But what next? How do I show the non-existence of such $\beta?$ I mean the fact that it can be divided by $3$ just shows that there is a subgroup which is isomorphic to $C_3$ for this $O_K:\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d_1}+\sqrt{d_2}]$ as an additive group but what can I deduce after that?

Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

In $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{d_1},\sqrt{d_2}]$ we have $4$ distinct maximal ideals above $3$:

$(3,  \sqrt{d_1}\pm 1, \sqrt{d_2}\pm 1)$ all with residue field $\Bbb{F}_3$.

The product of those 4 ideals is $(3)$.

Thus the same holds in $O_K$.

If $O_K=\Bbb{Z}[b]$ then the maximal ideals above $3$ would be of the form $(3,b-n)$ with only $3$ possible choices for $n$, not $4$.